# Django does not create ImageField on Postgres

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I added a new ImageField in my `models.py`:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    [more_fields_here]
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pictures', null=True)
```

I ran `python manage.py makemigrations` and then `python manage.py migrate` without any errors.

But when I run my application I am getting:

```
ProgrammingError at column authentication_user.profile_picture does not exist
```

I checked in the Postgres database and the column `profile_picture` does not exist.

I deleted the migrations and tried again, but I am still getting the same error.

In the `migrations/0001_initial.py` there is the line:

```
('profile_picture', models.ImageField(null=True, upload_to='profile_pictures')),
```

But why does the column **not** exist in the table?

Comment: Did you maybe modify your migration file manually? I'd suspect that Django thinks that `0001_initial` is already migrated and this is why it doesn't add this field. I'd also suggest to try `python manage.py migrate appname zero` to rollback all migrations and then run `python manage.py migrate` again.

Comment: Have you set [`AUTH_USER_MODEL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to your custom user model? Are you seeing the `[more_fields_here]` fields in the database?

Comment: @Chris, I can confirm that I have set  the ``AUTH_USER_MODEL``. All other fields are in the database as expected. The problem is only with this field.

Comment: Does `manage.py sqlmigrate <app_name> 0001` include SQL to create the column?

Comment: @Chris yes the column is included in the SQL CREATE command: ``CREATE TABLE "authentication_user" ("id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, [...] "profile_picture" varchar(100) NULL);``

Comment: @Kamil, with the ``python manage.py migrate appname zero`` it worked, but that deleted all the entries of the database table. Is there not a better solution?

Comment: It looks like it was something messed with migrations, it's not recommended to modify migration files manually. But in your case I would remove this line with `profile_picture` from `0001` migration, and then I would try to run `makemigrations` to create `0002` migration only with a new field `profile_picture`. Then you could `migrate`. To clarify, maybe it explains you what I'm suggesting, Django stores in its way which migrations were applied. If you already applied `0001` and then you modify it, Django will ignore those changes, because it thinks that `0001` was already migrated.

Comment: @Kamil, that worked perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: @Galil great! You're welcome!

Comment: @Kamil, you can add your comment as an answer so that other people who might have a similar issue can find it more carefully.

Comment: @Galil good point, I've added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it was something messed with migrations, it's not recommended to modify migration files manually. Django stores information which migrations were already applied, if you modify `0001` migration which is already applied and run `migrate` again those modifications won't be applied. Of course I don't know if this exactly what happened to you, but it looks like `profile_picture` field was added after `0001` was applied.

The easiest way to fix this (without rollbacking any migrations):

1. remove field `profile_picture` from `0001` migration
2. run `makemigrations` again (`0002` with new field `profile_picture` should be created)
3. run `migrate`